# Don't wrap commands in []/[[]])

Tags: shell-script, shell

I just learn shell, i use vscode and shell-check to check systax. Here is an example of what i'm doing: I want to check a string exist on a certain text file

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
Echo "Enter user"
if [ $grep -q binhqq "text.txt"] ; then
  echo "Found"
fi
```

But they it warn me that `Don't wrap commands in []/[[]])`, why i have that warning, thnk you a lots

Comment: Do you have a command called `Echo`?

Comment: https://shellcheck.net/ will also help you with syntax issues. Paste your code there and (try to) fix the errors it reports

Comment: @roaima: but OP says they use shellcheck

Comment: Oh, is that what it's saying? I thought it must be some feature of vscode

Answer (score 7):

There are some basic problems in your script:

- you use `Echo` instead of `echo`
- you use `$grep` instead of `grep` - `$` is used to dereference a
  variable, you don't need it here
- you tell user to `Enter user` but don't really read any input

Shellcheck warning:

```
SC1072: Expected test to end here (don't wrap commands in []/[[]]). Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

is raised because `grep -q binhqq "text.txt"` is not a valid EXPR
inside `test` (see `help test`) and can be fixed by either using
[command
substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html):

```
if [ -n "$(grep binhqq text.txt)" ] ; then
```

(tests whether the output of `grep` is non-empty) or by getting rid of `[` and `]` altogether:

```
if grep -q binhqq "text.txt" ; then
```

(relies on the exit-status of `grep` instead).

Comment: but as a newbie like me, i dont userstand why cant use grep in [] . why ?  Please help

Comment: @LêQuốcKhánh: have you read `help [`?

Comment: I never read that before, i will read that right now

Comment: @LêQuốcKhánh [`[` is not a part of the `if` syntax](https://superuser.com/a/1533643/432690). `[ … ]` does not wrap anything. `[` is a *command* and `]` is its last argument. You use the command when you need it. To know if you need it, learn what it does.

Comment: I agree with you, `[` is a command in Bourne shell, however I believe in Bash (and maybe in other Bourne-like shells) `[` is a built-in, along with `test` (to which it is an equivalent).  It does differ from `[[` though, which is shell syntax and not a command (built-in or otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

Note the syntax of `if` (bash has a really useful interactive `help` system)

```bsh
$ help if
if: if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; ]... [ else COMMANDS; ] fi
    Execute commands based on conditional.

    The `if COMMANDS' list is executed.  If its exit status is zero, then the ...
```

See that after the `if` keyword, bash wants to see COMMANDS. There's nothing
specific about `[` or `[[` or `((` -- those are just builtin commands or keywords. We
could put any any list/pipeline of commands in there.

The magic is that `if` branches
based on the **exit status** of COMMANDS: if the exit status is **zero** then the "true" branch is taken; any **non-zero** exit status puts you in the "false" branch.

Comment: According to `man bash`, `[` is actually a builtin command, but `[[` and `((` are parts of the shell syntax. They are described in completely different places of the manual ;)

Answer (score 1):

`[` is an alias of the command `test` (or a built-in that does the same).

So when we do `[ grep …` we are doing `test grep ….` this invokes the command `test` and passes it `grep …`. Then `test` say “I don't grok what you say `grep …`”.